# In chisel, How to generate serval Module with different parameter?

Tags: scala, chisel, rocket-chip

I have a Module `monit` which has an parameter `threshold` , then I want to generate serval(e.g.8) Module monit in the wrapper with different threshold . But when I use

```
val monits = Seq.fill(8)(Module(new monit(32)))
```

to create 8 modules monit, they all have same threshold, how can I deliver different  threshold parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```scala
val thresholds = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
val monits = thresholds.map(th => Module(new monit(th)) )
```

I typed this on my phone and have not tested the code, but should give an idea about using scala collections and `map` for the purpose.